# Creating a new list from the means of a list of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numpy

I've defined a function called CalcspeedAngle

```
def CalcspeedAngle(k):
    xpos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    ypos = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
    turnrates = [entry/3.099 for entry in xpos][::k]   
    vts = [entry/3.099 for entry in ypos][::k]
    return(turnrates,vts)
```

then I write

```
turnrates, vts = CalcspeedAngle(k)
```

My question is: How can I create two new lists (m1list and m2list) that contain the averages of the turnrates and vts with k = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20? In other words, how can I create:

```
m1list = [mean(flattened(turnrates(k=1))), mean(flattened(turnrates(k=2))), ...]
m2list = [mean(flattened(vts(k=1))), mean(vts(turnrates(k=2))), ...]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should start by finxing your codes indentation - and I do not really get your problem... also add what is inside `m1ist,m2list` (the data) to your question and what you exactly mean with flatten,  why you use turnrates as function etc.

Comment: My problem ist that my code doesn't work. The data is quite complicated. That's why I haven't included it. When I insert different k's, the turnrates and vts lists of lists should be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to simplify your code is to perform one iteration over `range(10)`, unpack your 2 lists of lists, calculate the mean for each, and append them to your result lists:

```
def lists_of_means():
    m1list = []
    m2list = []

    for i in range(10):
        turnrates, vts = CalcspeedAngle(i)
        m1list.append(np.mean(turnrates))
        m2list.append(np.mean(vts))

    return m1list, m2list
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I type this code  and then on the next line if I type  m1list, then Python gives me an empty list [ ]. If I type in     m1list, m2list = lists_of_means()     on the next line instead of m1list, then Python shows me an error (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'). Do you have any ideas why this is?

Comment: Sorry, no. I suggest you can improve your question by provided a [mcve].  This would include a mock *minimal* (but complete) `CalcspeedAngle` class.

Comment: Aha! I fixed the problem by using   m1list.append(np.mean([item for sublist in turnrates for item in sublist]))    instead of m1list.append(np.mean(turnrates))

Comment: @IwanPhillips, If this helped, please consider accepting (green tick on left). Or, of course, feel free to post your solution as a separate answer.